# How to select an option with putty via ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, debian, putty, bacula

How do I select yes or no?

[see screenshoot here](http://srv.wyns.me/photos/Capture.JPG)

I'm using ssh with putty. It should be **tab** key to switch between the options but it's not working.

In this case it's the removal of bacula and I had the same issue when installing.

The client is Putty on windows and the server is running Debian.

Thanks for your help,

regards,

John

Comment: `TAB` should work with putty. However, for the given dialog I'd try left/right arrow first.

Comment: arrows didn't recact also wired ...

Comment: Then I have no further clue, except maybe http://superuser.com/questions/243909/putty-keyboard-mapping.

Comment: I check your link and it was already configured this way.
I try it from ubuntu from a VM and it succed.

I will check the putty configuration more deeply

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing a setting in putty's configuration:

Under Window -> colours

Check the box **Allow terminal to specify ANSI colours**